# Is it possible to add dashboard component on a custom object home page

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component

Is it possible to add dashboard component on a custom object home page.

[image]

I would appreciate for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to add charts to a visualforce page by using the tag:

> analytics:reportChart

Please check this out.

[Analytics Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm)

You can use something similar to this:

```
 <apex:page>
      <analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”>/analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You will also have to override the custom object tab with a visualforce which will have the Analytics chart as well as enhanced list view.

Comment: Hi @RajeshShah : Can you provide me the code for any custom object that would have dashboards on the top and enhanced list view down the bottom

Comment: Hi @viasur: Can you provide me the code for any custom object that would have dashboards on the top and enhanced list view down the bottom